# Reusing the Stack Overflow Login Buttons

Tags: discussion

I like how you guys have styled your login buttons.

I consider it to be the best social login that I have used, and will therefore be using it as a model to style mine. My question is, I can see the styles and everything when I view source so I know what I need to do and similarly with the provider icons.

Would you guys have any objection to me just copying your style and login images, if feels somewhat reasonable to ask since the login logos are not even your trademarks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "login logos"?

Comment: Perhaps OP was refering to the "Log in with ..." logos for external auth providers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about the OpenID login control, Stack Exchange uses the open source [OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/), which you can simply download and integrate into your own project in accordance with the project's [BSD license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php).

It comes with the icons for the various popular OpenID providers already, and you can style it as you see fit.

Comment: The demo login control looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dMNg.png.  The Stack Overflow login looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pXNO6.png.  The Stack Overflow buttons have drop shadows, rounded corners, they gain outlines and move on hover, they highlight on click, and have *log in with* text above the logos.  The additional login options appear only after clicking "Show more login options …" instead of being visible all the time, and there's an additional text field to enter your own OpenID.  **Does "style it as you see fit" mean "copy Stack Overflow's styling?**

Comment: I'm not a fan of copy+paste, if that's what you mean. Implementing those enhancements is a fairly minor exercise even without looking at the specific CSS + JavaScript used, though.

Comment: Additionally that sort of styling is rather commonplace, you wouldn't be found to be duplicating the look and feel without duplicating the entirety of the page. And since each site on the SE network is uniquely themed, the most you would be doing is laying out a grid of buttons with images instead of text that had rounded corners and styling.

Comment: Unless, of course, you can't do CSS and you MUST rip off their exact code. But that's just me.

Comment: Thanks guys, we evaluated OpenID Selector and we've gone with our own OAuth solution. Thanks for sharing, I guess I was hoping for some insights in to the UX decisions as well as the API/styling, but the question didnt reflect that. But all very helpful stuff